# C# How add mysql connection to separated class?

Tags: c#, mysql, class

Is it possible to add MySQL connection to another Class (as public) in C# and call the connection in other classes instant of typing all connection code lines every time and for each part of the program ?

**Is it secure and correct to do something like that ?**

*For EX, in PHP we can use include, is any other way in C# to do the same* ?

*I know we can use Public classes in C# and call them in other part of program, like using function in PHP, so I would like to know if it's secure to use same method in C# for MySQL connection !*

And finally, if someone can explain me how to make it happen (have MySQL connection in separated class) or send me a link where it explain that !

Comment: Take a look at the SO doc: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4811/accessing-databases/16931/connection-strings#t=201610171253488396361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I learned, it's not a good idea to use MYSQL connection info into the app and so I just created a PHP file on my server and I use **webclient post** to send and receive data to and from the PHP file and I have my database connection into my PHP file too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called data Access layer. I suggest you to look at entity Framework also.